# Colour just the top border of geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

A chart with a lot of bars looks very squished, for instance -

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:1000, y = (rnorm(1000)), fill = sample(c('a','b','c'), 1000, replace = T)), aes(x, y, fill = fill)) +  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

I have a chart for a similar dataset which I feel I will be able to make more sense out of by just colouring the top border of the bar. I'm unable to achieve this. The closest I can do is incorporate a `geom_step` but this also adds vertical lines where the y value changes and this crowds the chart even more. `geom_point` sizes aren't necessarily synced with the separation on the x axis so they spill over to the side for small x values. The only sure shot solution I'm able to think of is to actually manipulate the data such that I'm able to draw `geom_segment`s to do my work for me. Is there any other way

PS: I need to stick to this format for reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `geom_errorbar()` and set `ymin=` and `ymax=` to your `y` values. Then you can play with `width=` and `size=` to get the look you need.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:1000, y = (rnorm(1000)), fill = sample(c('a','b','c'), 1000, replace = T))) +  
      geom_errorbar(aes(x=x,ymin=y,ymax=y,color=fill),size=0.5,width=3)
```

[image]